# PayPal IPN with Adaptive Payments - how do I send item_number values?

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm developing a retail site which has an embedded PayPal system which uses chained payments (so that commission for every sale goes to a third party).

I want to update my database when an order is made. I want a user to buy an item and for the stock listed in the database to be decreased. For this, I need the item number (custom 6-digit numbers I'm using).

When the IPN message comes through, there are variables called:

item_number1
item_number2
item_number3 
etc, for every item.

However, all values are empty. How do I send the item numbers to PayPal for them to be sent back in the IPN message?

My request for sending items to PayPal via SetPaymentOptions works something like this:

```
$nvpstr .= "&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[$key].name=$product[Name]";
            $nvpstr .= "&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[$key].price=$productTotalPrice";
            $nvpstr .= "&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[$key].itemCount=$quantity";
            $nvpstr .= "&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[$key].itemPrice=$product[Price]";
            $nvpstr .= "&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[$key].identifier=$product[ID]";
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values at the query string of your IPN url.

When you define your ipn URL in a form like:

```
http://mydomain.com/notify.php
```

attach the variables

```
http://mydomain.com/notify.php?customvar1=customval1&customvar2=customval2...
```

you can also add these vars to an array, serialize it and use base64_encode instead.

e.g.

```
$items = array('customvar1' => 'customval1');
$ipnUrl = "http://mydomain.com/notify.php?params=" . base64_encode(serialize($items ));
```